# Delete Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to delete an instance from GUI web tool. It is showing that the instance have been deleted and it is removed from the list. Also the desk have been deleted. But after some time it is coming back in the list. Can some one please tell me what is the issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you see in your Compute Engine Operations page? Is listed as correctly deleted?

Comment: Was this instance created by one of the launch-click-to-deploy software in your Developers Console? If this is the case, you will need to remove the instances with the button provided in this page to 'Delete cluster'

Comment: @Marilu Hi, No the instance was created using "New Instance" button  in Compute Engine Console. I can not find any thing for "Delete Cluster". Can you please help ?

Comment: I was referring to the deploy software in GCE as Cassandra, RabbitMQ, etc. So if this option was used to create the instances, you will have a button to delete them in your Developer Console in the 'Overview' section at the bottom, and then selecting the software that was deployed. If it's a start-up script that is bringing up the instance, check in the 'Operations' section which account is doing this.

Comment: I get the same problem. Do you had any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As mention on my previous comment, if you have installed any of the click to deploy software packages in GCE, you need to delete the cluster in the same page.
If this is not the case, in the Developers Console, the 'Operation' option, provides information of instance being created and by whom. This can give you an idea on what is sniping back the instance. If is's a service account, you need to find the script that is creating the instance and stop it.